# Ad-Hoc Distribution of app and revoking access

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

If I create an ad hoc distribution profile and successfully sent out an app in an ad-hoc fashion to a number of users, does deleting that profile then remove the app from that user's device or stop it from being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the .mobileprovision is installed on the device, that version of the app will continue to work on the device until the provisioning profile expires. If you delete the profile from the device the app will no longer function, but will remain on the device. They will get a warning saying they don't have valid provisioning to run the app if they try and launch it.

Comment: How long is the provisioning profile valid for then (assumedly 1 year?)

Comment: An ad-hoc profile is valid for 3 months. A developers provisioning profile is valid for one year.

Comment: @Mahesh the app will still function on existing devices. When you give someone an adHoc build, it installs a physical copy of the provisioning profile onto the device. The device checks for this certificate, and not the one in the provisioning portal.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.
There is no way to remove the app from the users device, other then either asking them or wait until the profile will expire.